# updating gridview rows separately?

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I would like to be able to update / access each row's "payee" field separately.
this is how I create the table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DateTime fromdate = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
dt = service.GetTransactions(accID, fromdate, DateTime.Now);
transactions.DataSource = dt; 
transactions.DataBind();
```

I would like to know if I can create the table in a way that will allow me to access each row separatley.
thanks

[this is currently the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZExx0.png)

Comment: `allow me to access each row separatley.` there are numerous ways to do this, what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to give the user the ability to change the name inside the payee field, but to do it separately.

Comment: What do you mean by “separately”? Also, we can see the data is in a table, but how is the “user” accessing the table? We can assume you are  using some UI and it has some type of “grid” and the grid uses the table as a data source...And, you want the user to be able to change a “payee” name in that grid, however, what UI interface are you using? WPF, Winforms… other?